# JBoss server and CouchDB server behind Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, jboss, proxy, couchdb

I have two servers on my local machine. One is a JBoss server running on port 8080
and the other is a CouchDB server running on port 5894. I can access each of them at
localhost:8080 and localhost:5984 respectively. Due to ajax same-domain restriction,
I need to access both the jboss and couchdb from example.com or at least the couchdb from example.com/couch. I heard and read
that apache's reverse proxy config can help with this. But so far I am unable to get it working.
I am running apache 2.2.19 on Win32. Can someone help with the config to achieve this?

Comment: I voted to migrate this to serverfault.com. I am not sure if or when it will migrate, but you may have better luck asking about Apache httpd, reverse-proxying, and mod_rewrite there. That site is full of people who do that all the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CouchDB v1.1.0, it has a built-in proxy. Perhaps it can be your primary web server, handling some queries and forwarding the rest to JBoss? There are some restrictions, primarily that you do not have the sophisticated control like httpd `mod_rewrite` would give you.

Log in to the Futon administration interface (`/_utils`). In the configuration section, click "Add a new section" at the very bottom. The section is `httpd_global_handlers`; the option is up to you, for example: `/_jboss`; and the value is an Erlang expression, `{couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:8080">>}`. (Obviously you can choose any URL you want but this example should work.)

You can also set this directly over the HTTP API:

```
PUT /_config/httpd_global_handlers/_jboss HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json

"{couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<\"http://127.0.0.1:8080\">>}"
```

Now when you query CouchDB, everything is just like before. However, there is a new URL space `/_jboss/*` which will proxy directly through CouchDB and to JBoss.

If you need JBoss to be at `/` and CouchDB to be at `/couch` that is also possible using a CouchDB *vhost* and also some *rewrite* rules. (They are much simpler than Apache httpd `mod_rewrite`).

Comment: sorry but I am using couchdb 1.0.2. Also, I would prefer to have the proxying at the apache httpd layer. I want to be able to remove the apache httpd and have jboss working like before (with the only required change being listening from to 80 instead of 8080). I also want to be able to remove the couchdb dependency and httpd and have my jboss working as usual.

Comment: Perhaps I should add some extra information. On my jboss server, I have two web apps. I use virtual hosting on them to enable me access them at www.site1.com and www.site2.org. Now, I require couchdb at www.site2.org for persistence. Due to same origin policies, I would like to add the httpd to allow me access couchdb at www.site2.org/couchdb. Maybe I am doing something wrong because I am trying to make the httpd proxy handle a url that has only been defined in jboss virtual hosting (the www.site2.org).

Answer (score 1):

mod_proxy module and something like this?

```
ProxyPass /couch/ http://localhost:5894/
ProxyPassReverse /couch/ http://localhost:5894/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: this does not work for me. Should they be defined under separate apache virtual hosts or should I, for example, just put them at the bottom of the httdp.conf?

Comment: Yes, I have it in separate VirtualHost section.